# ¿Por qué el navegador agrega "/" a un endpoint utlizando QUERY PARAMETERS?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

Sé que es algo que quizás no tiene mucha relevancia de cara a la funcionalidad, sin embargo realmente tengo la duda del por qué ocurre esto.

Estoy realizando una API REST con Flask y Python 3.

tengo un endpoint "/usuario", mi objetivo es utilizar QUERY PARAMETERS para consultar datos de un usuario según su código. Lo que sucede es que al usar un cliente REST (Insomnia en mi caso) tiene éxito al consumir de esta forma (observa la URL):

[image: consumir API desde insomnia]

Al hacerlo desde un navegador (Brave, Chrome) este automaticamente le agrega un /

quedando así

```
http://localhost:5000/usuario/?cod=220ba2c8c713
```

Especial atención con el **/**

al ejecutar eso me retorna error 404, he leído documentación pero la verdad no me queda muy claro. (también he consultado a chatGPT pero nada claro).

Dejo el código relevante para esto:

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

#Rutas
from .routes import UsuarioRoutes

app = Flask(__name__)

def init_app(config):
    #.env config
    app.config.from_object(config)

    #Activa CORS para cada endpoint
    #CORS(app, resources={"/auth/login": {"origins": "http://localhost:5173"}})

    #Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(UsuarioRoutes.main, url_prefix = "/usuario")

    return app
```

**UsuarioRoutes.py**

```
main = Blueprint('usuario_blueprint', __name__)

#Tabla USUARIO
#para consultar: localhost:5000/usuario....
@main.route('', methods = ['GET'])
def datos_usuario():
    #has_access = Security.verify_token(request.headers) #se debe incluir en el header el token
    has_access = True
    if has_access:
        try:
            codigo_usuario = request.args.get('cod', '-1') #si no se especifica es -1
            usuario = UsuarioService.obtener_usuario_por_codigo(codigo_usuario)
            if (usuario):
                response = {
                    'codigo_usuario': usuario.codigo_usuario,
                    'rut_usuario': usuario.rut_usuario,
                    'numero_telefonico_usuario': usuario.numero_telefonico_usuario,
                    'nombre_usuario': usuario.nombre_usuario,
                    'tipo_usuario': usuario.tipo_usuario,
                    'fecha_creacion_usuario': usuario.fecha_creacion_usuario,
                    'fecha_fin_usuario': usuario.fecha_fin_usuario,
                    'vigente': usuario.vigente,
                    'codigo_sucursal': usuario.codigo_sucursal
                }
                return response, 200
            else:
                response = jsonify(
                    {'success': False ,
                     'message' : 'No se encontró un usuario'})
                return response, 404
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Failed to fetch' })
    else:
        response = jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Unauthorized'})
        return response, 401
```

Si modifico

```
@main.route('', methods = ['GET'])
```

por

```
@main.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
```

ya funciona la URL por el navegador (es decir, la que tiene el **/**) pero es muy ???

yo sé que simplemente podría usar

```
@main.route('/<string:codigo>', methods = ['GET'])
```

y obtener el código de esa forma (que es la que sale en todos lados), sin embargo me encantaría saber el por qué ocurre eso jeje, sin más que decir gracias.

Comment: Si pegas `http://localhost:5000/usuario?cod=220ba2c8c713`en un navegador, no se añade automáticamente una /. No puedo reproducir ese comportamiento en Firefox o Chrome